# How to investigate an emacs crash on linux

Tags: debugging

im not very technical and lately i have been getting random crashed the seem to kill emacs and even the emacs daemon. this is an example output from CLI

```
Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Backtrace:
emacs[0x507da9]
emacs[0x4ee96c]
emacs[0x50654e]
emacs[0x506773]
emacs[0x5067df]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x11080)[0x7f8e10656080]
emacs[0x4c5207]
emacs[0x458635]
emacs[0x45d7f2]
emacs[0x41c358]
emacs[0x41e46d]
emacs[0x41fb1a]
emacs[0x421bcd]
emacs[0x454554]
emacs[0x456155]
emacs[0x4d6b71]
emacs[0x4d8625]
emacs[0x4f4c99]
emacs[0x4f5bdd]
emacs[0x5a1f0a]
emacs[0x5a2727]
emacs[0x561d23]
emacs[0x59603b]
emacs[0x561b5b]
emacs[0x59603b]
emacs[0x561b5b]
emacs[0x561e28]
emacs[0x560666]
emacs[0x4ef4d1]
emacs[0x55fef5]
emacs[0x4f3b55]
emacs[0x4fd33b]
emacs[0x5604b2]
emacs[0x4eedec]
emacs[0x560453]
emacs[0x4eeda9]
emacs[0x4f3537]
emacs[0x4f3878]
emacs[0x418a4e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f8e102c7291]
emacs[0x4195da]
```

can anyone guide me on how to further explore this, what should i report and where?

Comment: I would imagine that running gdb on Linux is similar to other operating systems I use (e.g., OSX and Windows).  Build the Emacs 25 or master branch (developmental build) from source and leave everything including the source code right were it is.  Start the Emacs program under gdb and then run a backtrace when it crashes.  If possible, try to establish a recipe starting from `emacs -q` so that the development team can reproduce the same setup.

Comment: wow do i really need to build from source for a bug report? no other alternatives?

Comment: If you want to meaningfully participate in diagnosing the bug, then yes, build from source using at least Emacs 25 and make it crash under gdb.  You could also just try to avoid dealing with it by recursively bisecting your user-configuration by commenting stuff out and restarting Emcs repeatedly until you find out what is causing the crash.  If you can isolate the issue, then just don't do whatever is causing the crash.  If you have a reliable recipe, then report it to the Emacs development team.  You can also look for another prebuilt version and see if that performs any different.